# Como exibir no console uma string do lado de outra em C#?

Tags: c#, console

Estou tentando **printar** uma **string ao lado de outra**. Minha ideia é printar 2 quadrados, assim:

```
********   ********
*      *   *      * 
*      *   *      *
********   ********
```

Um do lado do outro e poder manipular a **quantidade deles usando um laço for** por exemplo. Eu tentei assim mas fica péssimo e eu nao consigo controlar a quantidade.

```
Console.WriteLine("********      ********");
Console.WriteLine("*      *      *      *");
Console.WriteLine("*      *      *      *");
Console.WriteLine("********      ********");
```

Comment: Quando diz em controlar a quantidade, é para mostrar mais de 2 caixas, ou várias caixas como essas sempre do mesmo tamanho ?

Comment: Seriam várias caixas como essa do mesmo tamanho uma do lado de outra mesmo, como por exemplo eu uso um for com 8 repetiçoes e ele printa 8 caixas como essa uma do lado da outra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta pensar em termos de linhas.

Todas as linhas têm o mesmo tamanho e uma estrutura básica:

- asteriscos: no seu caso, `********` são oito asteriscos no topo e na base (primeira e última linha)

  - já no meio (as demais linhas) só tem asterisco no início e fim. Ou seja, tem dois asteriscos e 6 espaços entre eles.
- espaços: entre os retângulos, há uma quantidade fixa de espaços (no caso, 6)

Para imprimir N retângulos, basta repetir esta estrutura N vezes. Obviamente que depois do último não precisa de espaços (visualmente não faz diferença, mas entendo ser desnecessário).

No seu exemplo são quatro linhas, então eu imprimo a primeira e a última usando os oito asteriscos, e as demais usando asteriscos com espaços no meio.

Ficaria assim:

```cs
// Método auxiliar para imprimir uma linha:
// - parteRetangulo é impressa várias vezes (controlada pela quantidade)
// - entre elas, imprime o separador (exceto depois da última)
static void ImprimeLinha(string parteRetangulo, string separador, int quantidade)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(parteRetangulo);
        if (i != quantidade - 1) // se não é a última
        {
            Console.Write(separador);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(); // no final pula a linha
}

// Desenha os retângulos
//
// Recebe o tamanho do retângulo (base e altura), a distância entre eles e a quantidade.
// Opcionalmente, recebe:
// - o caractere das bordas do retângulo (asterisco se nada for passado)
// - o caractere do "recheio" do retângulo (espaço se nada for passado)
// - o separador (que vai entre os retângulos - espaço se nada for passado)
static void ImprimeRetangulos(int tamanhoBase, int altura, int distancia, int quantidade,
                              char caractereBorda = '*', char caractereMeio = ' ', char caractereSeparador = ' ')
{
    // base e topo tem todos os caracteres iguals
    var baseTopo = new String(caractereBorda, tamanhoBase);
    // as linhas do meio (entre a base e o topo), tem o caractere da borda no início e fim, e entre eles tem o "recheio"
    var meio = $"{caractereBorda}{new String(caractereMeio, tamanhoBase - 2)}{caractereBorda}";
    // separador vai entre os retângulos
    var separador = new String(caractereSeparador, distancia);

    for (int i = 0; i < altura; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == altura - 1) // primeira ou última linha
            ImprimeLinha(baseTopo, separador, quantidade);
        else
            ImprimeLinha(meio, separador, quantidade);
    }
}
```

No seu caso, são dois retângulos com base 8 e altura 4, e com 6 espaços entre eles. Então bastaria chamar:

```cs
ImprimeRetangulos(8, 4, 6, 2);
```

Que a saída será:

```
********      ********
*      *      *      *
*      *      *      *
********      ********
```

---

Repare que deixei parametrizável os caracteres que você pode usar para a borda do retângulo, o "recheio" e o separador. Por exemplo, se quiser tamanhos e caracteres diferentes:

```cs
// base 5, altura 6, 3 espaços entre eles, repete 7 vezes
// mudei também os caracteres usados
ImprimeRetangulos(5, 6, 3, 7, '+', '-', '.');
```

Resultado:

```
+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++
+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+
+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+
+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+
+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+...+---+
+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++...+++++
```

Comment: +1 - Dessa forma é bastante portável, funciona tanto como em ambientes Windows como POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

> **AVISO:**
> Essa solução funciona apenas em ambiente Windows.
> O método `Console.MoveBufferArea()` não é suportado por
> sistemas operacionais POSIX.
> Aparentemente o padrão POSIX não estipula um método ou procedimento padronizado de edição ao buffer de console, ficando a cargo da implementação definir ou não, assim imobilizando o funcionamento de um método `Console.MoveBufferArea()` em sistemas operacionais não Windows.
>
> Veja a discussão https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23073
> Também veja [The Open Group Base Specifications-General Terminal Interface](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11)

Uma solução simples em sistemas operacionais Windows, que não envolva manipulações complexas de string, pode ser alcançada usando o método [`Console.MoveBufferArea()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.movebufferarea?view=net-7.0) que copia uma área especificada do buffer da tela para uma área de destino especificada dentro do buffer da tela.

O [buffer de tela](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-7.0#screen-buffer-and-console-window) é um atributo do console organizado como uma grade retangular de linhas e colunas em que cada interseção de grade ou célula de caractere pode conter um caractere.
A origem das coordenadas de célula de caractere no buffer de tela é o canto superior esquerdo (0,0).

O raciocínio é simples, cria-se um método que imprime um quadrado de asterisco na origem do buffer de tela, posição(0,0).
Então dentro de um laço de iteração [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement) imprime um quadrado no canto superior esquerdo do buffer de tela então com o método `Console.MoveBufferArea()` mova a informação das células de caracteres que contém esse quadrado para a esquerda mantendo a mesma linha de origem do quadrado e incrementando a coluna onde acontecerá a impressão de acordo um índice.
Ao sair do loop reimprima o quadrado na origem do buffer de tela.

```
using System;

class Program
{
  static void Quadrado()
  {
     Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
     Console.WriteLine("********");
     Console.WriteLine("*      *");
     Console.WriteLine("*      *");
     Console.WriteLine("********");  
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Console.Clear();
     for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
     {
        Quadrado();
        Console.MoveBufferArea(0,0,8,4,9*i,0); 
     }
     Quadrado();
  }
}
//******** ******** ******** ******** ********
//*      * *      * *      * *      * *      *
//*      * *      * *      * *      * *      *
//******** ******** ******** ******** ********
```

Modificando o algoritmo a cima é possível fazer a impressão dos quadrados na linha em que o cursor estiver posicionado. Nesse caso use a propriedade [`Console.CursorTop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.cursortop?view=net-7.0) para obter a posição da linha em que se encontra o cursor dentro da área de buffer de tela e [`Console.SetCursorPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-7.0) para definir a posição do cursor dentro da área de buffer de tela.

```
using System;

class Program
{
  static void Quadrado(int left, int top)
  {
     Console.SetCursorPosition(0,top);
     Console.WriteLine("********");
     Console.WriteLine("*      *");
     Console.WriteLine("*      *");
     Console.WriteLine("********");  
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("linha1\nlinha2\nlinha3\n");
     int Top = Console.CursorTop;
     for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
     {
        Quadrado(0, Top);
        Console.MoveBufferArea(0,Top,8,4,9*i,Top); 
     }
     Quadrado(0, Top);
  }
}
//linha1
//linha2
//linha3
//
//******** ******** ******** ******** ********
//*      * *      * *      * *      * *      *
//*      * *      * *      * *      * *      *
//******** ******** ******** ******** ********
```

Comment: transformar o console em ferramenta de design, eu não canso de me surpreender com a criatividade :D :D :D

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas isso é ou não  útil?

Comment: Augusto se responde a pergunta e a comunidade entende que a pergunta é útil e relevante para a comunidade, então a resposta é útil, inclusive está bem pontuada :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TxE7lu0